# Difference between by, close and near

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between "by", "close" and "near" when they refer to spatial distance? Example:

- He is by the door.
- He is near (to) the door.
- He is close to the door.

Answer (score -1):

> He's **by** the door.

This means he is right next to the door. He can just touch the door.

> He's **near** the door.
>   He's **close to** the door.

These 2 mean the distance between *him* and *the door* is small but probably not enough for *him* to touch *the door*. These 2 mean the same thing.

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoters explained why they have done it.